# Play 2.0 - authorization

Tags: http, scala, authorization, playframework-2.0

In previous versions of Play 2.0 there was the Secure Module to do authorization. What is the way to do it in Play 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at ZenTasks sample code https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks where `Secured` trait is used to provide security features.
It can be found in Application.scala file.

Answer (score 2):

For the authorization portion, you can use [Deadbolt 2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2), which provides authorization features but does not provide authentication features. There is not equivalent to the Secure module in core Play 2.0.